# Cannot import sentinelsat python module

Tags: arcgis, sentinelsat

I am a python newbie and am trying to get the sentinelhub module to work but have been receving this error message on my code:

import sentinelhub

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
import sentinelhub
ImportError: No module named sentinelhub

After I've downloaded the module using "pip install sentinelhub" on the windows command. I am currently using Python version 2.7.18. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sentinelhub requires a different version of Python.
From their own website they specify that it "requires Python >=3.7"

https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html